# Mysql syntax error on updating and all other functions

Tags: mysql, mysql2

I'm using Ubuntu 13 and i've installed mysql2 for my rails server.

In mysql console (`mysql -p`) i'm trying to change record value. My database called daysandnights, I got tables users with different fields.

```
use daysandnights

UPDATE users SET right = `administrator` WHERE id = 3;
```

And i got: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'right =`administrator`WHERE id = 3' at line 1`

I know there are lots of such questions, but... What's the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use backticks for strings but quotes while `right` is a reserved keyoword and it needs to be surrounded with backticks

```
UPDATE users SET `right` = 'administrator' WHERE id = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks! that's it. i'll accept your answer in 10 minutes :) as rules says